# Try/Catch exception help in Java

Tags: java

The program I am making has a console-based text menu to select an option between 1 and 2, I need it to catch for any input that isnt a number, and isnt a number between 1 and 2. This is what I have

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter a number ");
        System.out.println("1.");
        System.out.println("2.");
        number = scan.nextInt();
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("Arithmetic Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (!(number == 1) || !(number == 2)) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
```

Any insight on where I have gone wrong is appreciated!

Comment: You say you’ve gone wrong - where does the actual behaviour differ from the intended?

Comment: What's the problem? You didn't specify.

Comment: Putting in the number `3`, for example, isn't a system exception but a program-defined boundary. Use an if-statement for that *inside* the try-block.

Comment: You don't get an ArithmeticException from reading an int from a Scanner, as you are not doing any arithmetic. And a number is always either not equal to 1 or not equal to 2.

Comment: It won't throw an exception for you, you need to do the logic and throw the exception.

Comment: Exception will be thrown when you enter something which cannot be converted to int ... use an if statement as @DrewKennedy has suggested

Answer (score 1):

If you want to throw an exception, this is easy but take care with the condition:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = 0;
try {
    System.out.println("Enter a number ");
    System.out.println("1.");
    System.out.println("2.");
    number = scan.nextInt();
    if ((number != 1) && (number != 2)){
        throw new Exception(); 
    }
}
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("This is not a number");
}
catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Inside here because the number is not 1 or 2"); 
}
```

The condition

```
(number != 1) && (number != 2)
```

is `true` if `number` **is not** (1 or 2)

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can use

`if ((number != 1) || (number != 2))`

instead of

`if (!(number == 1) || !(number == 2))`

Comment: Sure, but why not just use `if (true)`, that's equivalent and simpler again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter a number ");
        System.out.println("1.");
        System.out.println("2.");
        number = scan.nextInt();
        if (number != 1 && number != 2){
            throw new Exception(); 
        }
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("Arithmetic Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Inside here because the number is not 1 or 2 "); 
    }
```